# how to parse this string in Python?

Tags: python, string, parsing

I have a file which contains each line in the following format

```
"('-1259656819525938837', 598679497)\t0.036787946"    # "\t" within the string is the tab sign
```

I need to get the components out

```
-1259656819525938837  #string, it is the content within ' '
598679497     # long
0.036787946   # float
```

Python 2.6

Comment: There are many tools for parsing strings. In order of increasing power and complexity they are 1: functions such as split, 2: regular expressions, 3: full fledged parsers. This task seems simple enough for split.

Comment: sorry to ask dumb questions, I was not aware of findall function. It should be closed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions from [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module:

```
import re
s = "('-1259656819525938837', 598679497)\t0.036787946"
re.findall(r'[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+', s)
% gives: ['-1259656819525938837', '598679497', '0.036787946']
```

Answer (score 0):

`"2.7.0_bf4fda703454".split("_")` gives a list of strings:

```
In [1]: "2.7.0_bf4fda703454".split("_")
Out[1]: ['2.7.0', 'bf4fda703454']
```

This splits the string at every underscore. If you want it to stop after the first split, use `"2.7.0_bf4fda703454".split("_", 1).`

If you know for a fact that the string contains an underscore, you can even unpack the LHS and RHS into separate variables:

```
In [8]: lhs, rhs = "2.7.0_bf4fda703454".split("_", 1)

In [9]: lhs
Out[9]: '2.7.0'

In [10]: rhs
Out[10]: 'bf4fda703454'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to extract number and float from string:

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "('-1259656819525938837', 598679497)\t0.036787946"
>>> re.findall(r'[-?\d\.\d]+', a)
['-1259656819525938837', '598679497', '0.036787946']
```

Comment: Actually, the character set in your regular expression is misleading. You probably meant it in a different way. Otherwise, if you still want to use a character set, maybe a simpler one would suffice: `re.findall(r'[-\d\.]+', a)`